Bench supply protection diode replacement
I have damaged a 30V 5A bench supply by connecting it to 21V in reverse polarity. It was on at the time, set to 21V 1.7A with no load. Maybe you guessed, I was attempting to charge a 5S LiPo pack but accidentally swapped the leads.
Upon making the connection something sizzled and a puff of smoke came out of the power supply. I immediately switched it off and let it rest. When I turned it back on, the front panel seemed fine, but there was no output and the display read 0V and max amperage with no load. Seemed to be an internal short.
Opened it up and everything looked fine. No odd smells either. I probed across the first component spanning the power rails, a beefy diode, and it was shorted. Made sense that it might be problematic, so I lifted one leg. Still tested shorted, and on the output rails the short was gone. Due to this, I figure it must be a protection diode. The power supply seems to work fine in the limited testing I've done without it.
EDIT: The diode is marked UF5408
Questions:

a) What is the precise function of this diode? b) Can I replace this diode with a similar one? c) Will the power supply work well enough without the diode?

a) Is it expected that this diode would fail shorted in my case? b) Is it likely that other damage was done to the supply? c) What further damage should I look for?

Why would this power supply have no fuse on the output?


Brief, laymen's terms responses would be best. Thanks.


The component should have printing on it, just read what it says? You'll have to de-solder it no matter. Most likely a TVS since it sits directly on the supply cables.

Look for markings on the diode (part number, codes).  The diode might be a Schottky diode or a fast recovery diode for reverse polarity protection.

Thanks guys, I initially thought the markings were just a manufacturer, but the part number is indeed there. I have edited the question accordingly. Still curious as to what exactly it does and if I should suspect any further damage.

It's there to protect against 'accidents' like you had. It also is useful if 2 power supplies are connected in series and the combination is shorted. This also prevents the output electrolytic from being reverse biased.
Its part number isn't critical; the PSU will work without it, but of course the protection it provides won't be there. You can use any diode with > 30 V & 5 A rating.

Thank you. I have a 1N5408 that I will install in its place. I'm curious if you might have a guess about the smoke that came from somewhere, given that the failed diode's package is intact. What else could be compromised? No capacitors have erupted, but should I look for leakage?
